# When and when not is a mapping table needed?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have a doubt regarding normalization.

I have three tables:

```
rule_set (id, name, creation_date, descrtiption)

input_scenario (id, name, creation_date, bitmask, description)

output (id, rule_set_id, input_scenario_id, key, value), fk(rule_set_id to rule_set.id, input_scenarion_id to input_scenario.id);
```

The idea is that I have some input scenarios configured. Then, whenever a new rule_set is created, for each input scenario a series of outputs are created.

This schema works fine, but I am in the doubt, for the sake of normalization, of whether I should create a mapping table like:

```
mapping (id, rule_set_id, input_id), fk (rule_set_id to rule_set.id, input_id to input.id)
```

And then my output table be like:

```
output(id, key, value, mapping_id), fk (mapping_id to mapping.id)
```

What is best practice and why?

Comment: Normalization involves identifying and maintaining functional and join dependencies in relations/tables. However, you didn't provide any dependencies. If I make assumptions based on your table and column names, I'd say your mapping table just adds an unnecessary bit of indirection. But I might be interpreting it wrong. Please list your dependencies for solid answers.

Comment: Updated with foreign keys for better undestanding.

Comment: I suggest you read up on [functional dependencies](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129955/how-to-represent-what-functional-dependencies-are) for a start.

Comment: And normalization.